# Ionic/AngularJs Navigation And Routing not Working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to AngularJs and Ionic, I am trying to follow [this example](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-2/) to create simple app but it is just showing blank screen and there is no error on console log.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="bloggerDemo">
    <ion-pane>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive"></ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-pane>
</body>

</html>
```

latestPosts.html

```
<ion-view title="Latest Posts">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="latestPost in latestPosts" class="item item-icon-right" sref="latestPosts.singlePost({post: $index})">
                <span>{{latestPost.title}}</span>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

singlePost.html

```
<ion-view title="Single Post">
    <ion-content padding='true'>
        <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
        <section>{{post.description}}</section>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('bloggerDemo', ['ionic'])

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/latestPosts')

    $stateProvider.state('latestPosts', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/latestPosts',
        template: '<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>'
    })

    $stateProvider.state('latestPosts.index', {
        url: '/latestPosts',
        templateUrl: 'templates/latestPosts.html',
        controller: 'PostsCtrl'
    })

    $stateProvider.state('latestPosts.singlePost', {
        url: '/:singlePost',
        templateUrl: 'templates/singlePost.html',
        controller: 'SinglePostCtrl',
        resolve: {
            singlePost: function ($stateParams, PostService) {
                return PostService.getPost($stateParams.post)
            }
        }
    })
})

app.controller('PostsCtrl', function ($scope, PostService) {
    $scope.latestPosts = PostService.latestPosts
})

app.controller('PostCtrl', function ($scope, singlePost) {
    $scope.singlePost = singlePost
})

app.factory('PostService', function () {
    var posts = [
        {
            title: 'lkad alkjdflak dfkljad f alkdsjf al',
            description: 'adflkajd fjad faldfj aldkjf lkdfj lakdj flaksd flkds flksdj flkadlkfkhaghoiahd fkasdjkasdjfkl ajf sdjfalksdj falj falkf '
        },
        {
            title: 'lkad alkjdflak dfkljad f alkdsjf al',
            description: 'adflkajd fjad faldfj aldkjf lkdfj lakdj flaksd flkds flksdj flkadlkfkhaghoiahd fkasdjkasdjfkl ajf sdjfalksdj falj falkf '
        }
    ];

    return {
        latestPosts: posts,
        getPost(function (post) {
            return latestPosts[post]
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: maybe templateUrl doesn't point to the right path and/or the right file(html)?

Answer (score 0):

try changing this:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="latestPost in latestPosts" class="item item-icon-right" sref="latestPosts.singlePost({post: $index})">
        <span>{{latestPost.title}}</span>
    </ion-item> 
</ion-list>
```

for this:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="latestPost in latestPosts" class="item item-icon-right">
        <a ui-sref="latestPosts.singlePost({post: latestPost.post_id })">
{{latestPost.title}} 
        </a>  
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Hope this Help you...

Answer (score 0):

after I read your code, I think I found the problem exist in your `app.js`

change this:

```
$stateProvider.state('latestPosts', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/latestPosts',
        template: '<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>'
    })
```

to this:

```
$stateProvider.state('latestPosts', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/latestPosts',
        template: "/templates.index.html" 
    })
```

It is essential to note that the abstract state always point to where the `<ion-nav-view>` exist.

Tell me if it works, Happy Coding.